# Browser Back Button Handling in Ajax Based Application

Tags: ajax, browser, button, back

Similar questions have been asked on SO, but I am still looking for a solution and not a workaround.

I am working on an Ajax based application and when the user clicks on the Browser Back Button it takes the user to the login page(every page after the login page is ajax loaded). Apparently, this is not what the user expected.

We recommended using Bread Crumbs to the client

```
*Page One >> Page Two >> Page Three*
```

but the client insists that they prefer to use the Browser Back Button. Is there a way where it is possible to somehow embed the Bread Crumb links to the Browser Cache...in other words, clicking the back button invokes the same actions which clicking the Bread Crumb links would?

Regards,
SB

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history is a good solution, that append & overwrite the location hash.

Comment: I tried plugins.jquery.com/project/history and if I understand correctly, it works only for GET requests. I am using DWR, and DWR uses POST and so this jquery plugin does not work for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the RSH (reallysimplehistory) javascript library: http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/