# Back button handling in Single Page Apps?

Tags: javascript, url, hash, single-page-application, dhtmlx

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160343/browser-back-button-handling-in-ajax-based-application) has been noted!

I've got an SPA based exclusively on the DHTMLX toolkit (fabulous stuff incidentally). One serious UX problem is with back button handling: there is none.

Their forum recommended 'any js routing library to handle state of the app in the url hash and restore it back'.

I am confused by this as the SPA has only the simplest HTML, is exclusively Javascript and does most communicating via WebSockets ... does this mean I have to store state on each button click/keypress?

So, ...

1. Does the panel have any recommendations on best practices?
2. Is there an existing library that will do this?
3. If said library is light on examples, can anyone provide a basic how-to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dhtmlx is a great framework for building SPAs.  Like all SPAs, the back button will simply take the user right out of app.  Also the user cannot bookmark anything.

So what you want to do is use javascript's `pushState()` which will allow you to control the url.

For example, suppose you show a search screen to go to a record.  The user enters the search criteria and presses search.  You bring in the results via ajax and update a grid.  Then the user selects the row and you go to a detail page (typical search functionality here).

At this point, you would want to use `pushState()` to change the url to something like:
`http:/me.com/search/23432`

This will allow the user to bookmark the page.  Then when the user leaves the detail page, use `pushState()` and set the url to `http:/me.com/search`

So you have complete control over the url.

The next thing you need to learn is `popState()`. This function is called when the url changes.  So suppose the user pushes the bookmark to go to "23432".  `popState()` will be called and you'll react accordingly.

That's basically it in a nutshell: `pushState()` and `popState()`.

Some older browsers do not react to pushState/popState. There are libraries floating around to handle older browsers using url hashing.  I am not too familiar with them as I am only supporting html5 browsers.

Comment: Brian, thank you. This is pretty much the conclusion I had reached. There is perhaps a fine line between the back button being treated as some kind of 'undo' mechanism. The legacy browser point is well made, fortunately I am able to dictate the use of HTML5 compliant varieties.

Comment: This isn't totally accurate.  As far as I know, there is no `popstate` function.  There's a popstate event, but it's accessed via either `window.onpopstate = function () {}` or `window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {})`

Comment: This solution still requires unique URLs, so it will not work if you're loading page content into a div.

Comment: as @SandyGifford mentioned: [popstate is an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)